# Linking external stylesheets on Linux Mint not working?

Tags: html, css, linux, linux-mint

I recently changed my operating system from Windows 7 to Linux Mint 14.

I often make web programs on my computer for practice, so I link external stylesheets and javascript files.

For some reason with Linux, when I link an external stylesheet, it doesn't work.
The HTML and CSS are in the same folder/directory.

Here is what I have tried:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Finder.css">
```

and

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/home/bradley/Programming/Finder.css">
```

I can't see to figure out why neither of them are working. Any solutions?
I was always able to link files on Windows just fine.

Comment: Are you sure that your CSS file is called `Finder.css` ?

Comment: Does the code work on a different machine (windows)?

Comment: @user2019515 yes and yes.

Comment: it's clearly a file hierarchy issue as the file structure between both operating systems differ considerably. I would check your file paths etc

Comment: @Vector But then the first option should work and that one doesn't either

Comment: let's take the first option for example, I assume the file name is correct etc (capital F). Is this style sheet link linked from a HTML document from within the same folder? or from an included php `include` header/nav section?

Comment: @Vector yes, they are from the same folder.

Comment: @Vector I just tried putting the files on a usb, and it worked. Yet it still doesn't work when on my HDD.

Comment: have you tried to open the inspector in chrome of FF, to check if the file is loaded or not, it might be a case sensitivity issue